# Unable to open a URL link with using urllib2 in chrome

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I'm able to open the webpage by simply entering the URL link in my chrome browser
But when i move this URL link to below code, it will prompt me the error message:

CODE:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.klse.info/companies/listed-companies/alphabet/A'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

ERROR:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Anyone have idea with this?
I tried to change the URL link to other link address and it does work.
Is the website set restriction or anything i should take care for?

Comment: I read some threads, many says the restriction is from Google. May i know is there any workaround to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get rid from HTTP Error 403: Forbidden?

Please refer to the below code...

```
url = 'http://www.klse.info/companies/listed-companies/alphabet/A'
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: How to do the same in python3? I use urllib.request package. It doesn't work.